# Looking for resources possibly books that have good exercises on Applications of Integration Volumes and Areas

Tags: calculus, reference-request, area, volume

Any books with difficult and more intuitive Questions on Applications of integration, Areas and Volumes. I'm currently using Stewart and Larson.

I am also looking for resources on sketching functions.